# Cannot login to single user mode on a MacBook Pro (A1502). Could it be because of a firmware lock?

Tags: macos

Recently I needed to get into single user mode on my computer; my MacBook Pro (A1502). So I did the traditional <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Except that this time a small box of text appeared in the centre of the screen, then went straight to the login screen.

Now this would make me think that the firmware lock is on. So I tried pressing the <kbd>Option</kbd> button. This got the expected result.

I could choose which drive to boot from.

I really need help!

This is what happens when I try to get into single user mode.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you need help for? You seem to have managed to boot onto your user account, right?

Comment: Check which screen matches, from this list - https://support.apple.com/HT204156 - or take a photo if none of the above.

Comment: @Kobe: can you boot in Recovery Mode? From what we can see in the picture, your volume is indeed locked, probably by Secure Boot, which is set in a separate chip on your Mac's logic board. Most modern Macs can't boot in Single User mode anymore because of that, among other things (APFS doesn't support Single User as extensively as HFS+ did, so to reduce the risk of user-made mistakes, Apple greatly reduced access to Single User mode; you have to be able to put your Mac in DFU-mode to access it, and you usually need a way to unlock/disable Secure Boot first).

Comment: Okay, thank you.